# Backtrace R script

Tags: r, backtrace

I have a folder with a lot of R scripts. I start sourcing one of them but I would like to know which ones are then called. Is there a way to produce this kind of backtrace or to echo a message whenever one of the files is sourced?

Comment: You really should change your workflow and build a package out of this.

Comment: Well indeed that's code that I "inherited" and my idea was to cut everything unnecessary so as to produce a minimal working collection of scripts. The problem is I cannot go through all the scripts themselves to check them one by one.

Comment: You could solve this by tracing the file access on the operating system level for the R process... Eg. when using Ubuntu Linux: [http://askubuntu.com/questions/191964/how-do-i-know-which-file-a-program-is-trying-to-access]